# How to mine smart contract deployment if creation gas requirement exceeds default block limit?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-deployment

My smart contract has lot's of functions, events, etc. Remix evaluates contract gas requirements as:

> "Creation": "47213 + 5396800\n"

I can deploy it in my private blockchain with increased in genesis block gas limit. As far as i know most miners in production blockchain use default block gas limit 4712388.

How can my contract be deployed in the future? I expect error messages like that transaction gas requirement exceeds block limit.

Obviously my original intention was to split it into few contracts, but after some review i decided it just has very complex business logics and nothing can be separated. So i'd prefer to leave it as-is if possible. Any options?

**Update**:

On https://ethstats.net/ i can see gas limit is about **6718946**. Does it mean non-default value ( > 4712388) is set at the moment for the most of miners?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to split up your contract into multiple, smaller contracts which can be deployed separately but can be linked and operate with each other.

Here is an example: [split token example](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24592/how-can-i-split-my-contract-up-into-different-smaller-ones#)

You can also look into using libraries: [Library driven development](https://blog.aragon.one/library-driven-development-in-solidity-2bebcaf88736), where a separate library contract has all of the functions but no state, but the functions can be called by the main contract that stores the state.

Comment: As i've noted there is no obvious way to split it (there are no logical "parts"). Any other options? I'll try to use Libraries approach.

Comment: There is no other way than splitting your contract, except waiting for the gas limit per block to increase until your old contract fits (since the gas limit is dynamic and can be voted up/down by miners).

Comment: i've updated the question (see "Update:"), can you comment it?